# remove_query_arg on options.php

Tags: wp-admin, settings-api

I have a normal WordPress settings page. It POSTs to options.php.

In options.php it uses wp_get_referer to redirect back to the page it came from.

I need to use remove_query_arg to remove an argument from the URL. Example:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin_settings_page&tab=90
```

I need to remove the tab=90 part. How can I do this via options.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using jQuery to do this. There might be a better way, but this works:

```
jQuery("input[name=_wp_http_referer]").val('admin.php?page=plugin_settings_page')
```

Comment: That's really far from a good idea.

Comment: @kaiser - I agree, but I don't know of another way. Do you?

Comment: Maybe you can add more than just the link you provided. Then it would be easier to show you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that `unset` the `tab` parameter, then call that function using `add_filter` to filter it from the `query_vars` array. The example value of `20` may need to be changed depending on when the `tab` parameter is currently being added.

```
  add_filter('query_vars', 'remove_queryvars_param', 20 );

    function remove_queryvars_param( $qvars )
    {
        unset($qvars['tab']);

        return $qvars;
    }
```